# EntityValidationErrors collection is piling up

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I'm very new to Entity Framework and working on validation process, i have the **EntityValidationErrors** collection in a try/catch block, every time code hits catch block, error count in EntityValidationErrors increases by one (normally). For example, i enter wrong data for test, first time i try, there is only 1 error in EntityValidationErrors collection, when i try it again, it increases by 1 again so it becomes 2 etc. Weird thing is, even when i rebuild the project, same errors stuck there. I mean, everytime there is an validation error, list gets bigger, i think it should reset itself at every **context.SaveChanges();** code, am i wrong? List only clears after i close Visual Studio and open it again.

Here is the code, i'm just checking the collection from the VS:

```
    try
    {
        kDB.commitTrans();
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        foreach (var err in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            errors += err.ValidationErrors;
        }
    }
```

Am i missing something here? Thanks

Comment: not sure what you are missing in your code but I'm sure what you miss in your question is your code.

Comment: I haven't included any code because there is almost none exists. I'm just looking EntityValidationErrors collection from Visual Studio GUI and like i said it keeps piling up until i restart the VS. I will include that now.

Comment: Rebuilding the project should kill the worker process and effectively end any application level variables in your project. I would look into what is actually being rebuilt when you rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

It seems i fixed it myself.

I was using a static class for DB operations, DBContext was in this class and it seems static classes don't die so easily. So, i was adding same entity everytime and while trying to save, that was the reason of so many errors.